# DDMS won't allow debugging

Tags: android, debugging, ddms

I'm attempting to use the DDMS debugger to connect to a process on a Nexus4 device. I've built a debug version of the application, added `android:debuggable="true"` to the manifest and also added `android.os.Debug.waitForDebugger();` to main MainActivity.

However the debug icon in DDMS remains greyed out, even though I can see the device and the application the DDMS list.
Any suggestions on how to resolve this?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[How to use Monitor (DDMS) tool to debug application step by step?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21946869/android-studio-how-to-use-monitorddms-tool-to-debug-application-step-by-step)

check this post you will get the answer.

In App Toolbar you will find "Android Device Monitor" just right beside the "SDK Manager". Click on this your DDMS will run. 
but
Problems:
1. It will close any adb connection and any debugging process. 
2. Unfortunately You will not be able to put debugger on any selected process. even this is a very good way of debugging your application.

Don't know why Google/InteliJ/Studio Developers are not fixing this issue.